# Properties of metallic hydrogen

Tags: energy, phase, stability, hydrogen

Given the possibility that metallic hydrogen may have recently been produced, and the massive media bloviation that followed, I am curious about some of the "properties" that I heard from multiple media outlets.

1. Does metallic hydrogen decompose to mono-atomic hydrogen, then recombine to diatomic hydrogen?
2. How much energy is produced by the decomposition?
3. How certain are we that it will be stable(ish) at STP?

Comment: The [Harvard Gazette](http://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2017/01/a-breakthrough-in-high-pressure-physics/) had a story on metallic hydrogen. One of the authors is quoted with "*One prediction that’s very important is metallic hydrogen is predicted to be meta-stable...*”. This sounds like an interesting perspective, but at this point, it seems to lack experimental proof.

Comment: Great link @KlausWarzecha . The research group did claim they made shiny, electrically conductive metallic hydrogen though. However, Wikipedia's metallic hydrogen page pointed out that "Shortly after the claim was published in Science, Nature's news division published an article stating that some other physicists regarded the result with skepticism. Recently, prominent members of the high pressure research community have criticised the claimed results,  questioning the claimed pressures or the presence of hydrogen at the pressures claimed." So, it is definitely controversial!

Comment: Regarding stability, like @KlausWarzecha said, it's predicted to be meta-stable. The grand claim is that it will be a room-temp solid (the Harvard group wasn't sure if they had liquid metal or solid metal) superconductor, also having enormous energy density, as you would imagine. Unfortunately, according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen): "In February 2017, it was reported that the sample of claimed metallic hydrogen was lost, after the diamond anvils it was contained between broke." So for now, it sounds like it's more "meta" than "stable" ;)

Comment: @airhuff Glad that you had a look at the more recent Wkipedia article, which I didn't do. A detailled comment on the initial article is freely available at [arxiv.org](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.07192). Your closing statement is right on the button :)

Comment: I don't know if anyone *expects* metallic hydrogen to be metastable. Lots of people sure would love that to be true, since it's a very energy dense fuel and could be a room-temperature superconductor, but metastability is more just wishful thinking than a predicted property.